# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3: "This project uses SQL Server Express LocalDB. Microsoft recommends that you use SQL Server Express with IIS"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and Update 3

I am getting the following irrelevant error when I open my project:

> This project uses SQL Server Express LocalDB. Microsoft recommends that you use SQL Server Express with IIS"

[image]

Before I click on "Don't ask again" I like to know what is the root of the irrelevant warning and how to address it properly?

Answer (score 2):

"SQL Server Express" and "SQL Server Express LocalDB" are very different.
The second one is a file-based database, so you need to configure the connection string specifying the path where the file .mdf is located.
The first is a real database server, so the connection string must include the server name (or the public ip), the username and the password.
The dialog simply suggest you to download and install SQL Server Express, that it's the best method to develop an application with database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: I am not using either of express or localdb. I connect to actual SQL server. That is why I think the warning does not apply to my project at all.

Comment: It's very strange. Try to search inside your entire solution for the string (LocalDB). The dialog tells that your project use a LocalDB connection, so somewhere there is a reference to it.